# How to add HTML class to main menu list?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

Theme Developer shows me that I need to use [theme_links()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7)

I can use this function, but I want to alter markup for main menu only.

I've tried funtion names: mytheme_links__menu_main_menu or mytheme_links__system_main_menu

but it seems that these function aren't invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this to create a theme key in your template file like this:

```
function THEMENAME_theme(){
    $items = array();

    $items['custom_main_menu'] = array(
      'variables' => array('links' => array()),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

And then use the function below

```
function THEMENAME_custom_main_menu($menu){
  $menu['links'][367]['#below'][526]['#attributes']['id'] = "news_ma_international";
  // this will add id to link # 367
}
```

Now to print the main menu in your page.tpl.php use something like this

```
 <?php $main_menu_tree = menu_tree(variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu')); ?>
                <?php print theme('custom_main_menu', array(
                  'links' => $main_menu_tree,
                  'attributes' => array(
                    'id' => 'main-menu-links',
                    'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
                  ),
                  'heading' => array(
                    'text' => t('Main menu'),
                    'level' => 'h2',
                    'class' => array('element-invisible'),
                  ),
                )); ?>
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: I've found that preprocessing custom menu is much easier. For main menu? Major pain in the ass

Comment: @drupality: I am not sure I understand your message.